# Most efficient way to print all lines with duplicated field?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

The following file, fruit_notes.txt, has three pipe-separated columns: fruit, color, and tasting notes. I would like to print all lines that have a duplicated color field. Order is not important.

```
banana|YELLOW|My turtle likes these.
cherry|RED|Sweet and tasty
grapefruit|YELLOW|Very juicy
grape|PURPLE|Yummy
lemon|YELLOW|Sour!
apple|RED|Makes great pie
orange|ORANGE|Oranges make me laugh.
```

This works...

```
> grep -F "`awk -F"|" '{print $2}' fruit_notes.txt | sort | uniq -d`" fruit_notes.txt
banana|YELLOW|My turtle likes these
cherry|RED|Sweet and tasty
grapefruit|YELLOW|Very juicy
lemon|YELLOW|Sour!
apple|RED|Makes great pie
```

However, it seems like an awkward (no pun intended) solution. It reads the file twice: once to find the duplicates in the color field, and again to find the lines matching the duplicate colors. It is also error-prone. For example, the following line would be incorrectly printed:

```
jalapeños|GREEN|My face turns RED when I eat these!
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe using awk alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This changes the order of the output but it only requires reading the file once:

```
$ awk -F'|' '$2 in a{if(a[$2])print a[$2];a[$2]=""; print; next} {a[$2]=$0}' fruit_notes.txt
banana|YELLOW|My turtle likes these.
grapefruit|YELLOW|Very juicy
lemon|YELLOW|Sour!
cherry|RED|Sweet and tasty
apple|RED|Makes great pie
```

How it works:

1. `$2 in a{if(a[$2])print a[$2];a[$2]=""; print; next}`

   If `$2` is a key in associative array `a`, then (a) if `a[$2]` is non empty, print it, (b) Set `a[$2]` to empty, (c) print the current line, and (d) skip the rest of the commands and start over on the next line.
2. `a[$2]=$0`

   If this is the first time we have encountered `$2`, save the current line in `a` under the key `$2`.

Comment: That's brilliant. I wasn't sure if it was possible to do it in one pass. Doing some reading now to understand the magic that makes it work!